# Can I pass over a formattable string to a string builder?

Tags: c#, .net-core

in .NET you have new overloads now for StringBuilder for string interpolation: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/string-interpolation-in-c-10-and-net-6/#interpolating-into-stringbuilders

These overloads make use a of a custom interpolated string handler and if I understand it correctly it is very likely allocation free, at least in some scenarios. (Given that the string builder has enough capacity). So it does not allocate a new string and then sends it to the string builder, but it sends the different parts to the string builder directly.

I have a custom class that wraps a string builder. Can I somehow pass over an interpolated string to this method to benefit from this performance improvements?

Here is an example what I would like to achieve:

In my case I have a HtmlWriter with the the following method:

```
void Attr(string name, string value);
```

and it is uses like this

```
.Attr("width", $"{width}px");
```

I can optimize this with an overload like

```
.Attr("width", width, "px");
```

but there are too many cases to write overloads.

So I would like to have a signature like this

```
.Attr(string name, ref FormattebleString value); // Must be a struct or so
```

Comment: Can you share some examples of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It is ugly and a lot of code, but could be worth it.

You cannot pass over a formatted string or so to the string builder, but you can write you own handler. In this handler you can just wrap the handler from the string builder:

```
[InterpolatedStringHandler]
public ref struct TryWriteInterpolatedStringHandler
{
    private StringBuilder.AppendInterpolatedStringHandler inner;

    public TryWriteInterpolatedStringHandler(int literalLength, int formattedCount, HtmlWriter writer, string name)
    {
        writer.AttributeName(name);

        inner = new StringBuilder.AppendInterpolatedStringHandler(literalLength, formattedCount, writer.StringBuilder);
    }

    public void AppendLiteral(string value)
    {
        inner.AppendLiteral(value);
    }
    
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the interpolated string handler is invoked first, so you cannot write the attribute name in the writer. So I had to solve it like this:

1. Write the start of the attribute in the handler.
2. Write the end of the attribute in the writer.

```
public class HtmlWriter
{
    private readonly StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public StringBuilder StringBuilder => sb;

    public void Attr(string name, [InterpolatedStringHandlerArgument("", "name")] ref AttrInterpolatedStringHandler value)
    {
         sb.Append('"');
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public void AttributeName(string name)
    {
        sb.Append(name);
        sb.Append("=\"");
    }
}
```

It also works with interfaces somehow, but you have to expose some implementations. Here: the StringBuilder property and the AttributeName method.